# Matching input names on keyup

Tags: jquery, keyup

Within this function I want to check that the focused input is a specific input, I want to do this by matching the input names together.

Is something like the below snippet possible?

```
$('body').on("keyup", "input", function() {

    if( $(this) == $('input[name="title"]'))
        alert('ok');

});
```

When I console.log `$(this)` it returns an object. I'm not sure how I'd go about checking the object for the input name.

Comment: `if ($(this).is("<selector>")) {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about object comparision but you could use instead

```
if ($(this).attr('name') == 'title')
    alert('OK');
```

avoiding creation of object juste for comparison ;)

You can also write a more specific filter to directly listen on the good element :

```
$('body').on("keyup", "input[name=title]", function() {

    // do your stuff

});
```